# Detecting state changes when someone starts a screen share - discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot that notifies me whenever someone starts a new stream.

```
const streamChannelId = 'MY-channel-id';


const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences] });

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready');
});



client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {

    console.log('oldPresence:', oldPresence);
    console.log('newPresence:', newPresence);

    if (!newPresence.activities) return;
    
    newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
        if (activity.type === "STREAMING") {
            const streamChannel = newPresence.guild.channels.cache.get(streamChannelId);
            if (streamChannel) {
                streamChannel.send(`${newPresence.user.tag} started a stream at ${activity.url}.`);
            } else {
                console.log('Stream channel not found.');
            }
        }
    });
});



client.login('my-key')
```

This works **only** when I started an **Activity** this doesn't work when I start a stream.
From the research I did it should work when a user streams as well but it doesn't work.

Needless to say my bot has all of the permissions.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Give `bot.on("voiceStateUpdate")` a shot. `VoiceState` has a `streaming` property, so I assume you get updates from that event.

Comment: I tried client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {console.log('oldPresence:', oldPresence);
    console.log('newPresence:', newPresence);}); 
then tried muting/unmuting and disconnecting/connecting, still doesnt work.

------------
edit : 
I didnt get the intent :  GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's not "presenceUpdate" that should be used but "voiceStateUpdate"
and the intent :

```
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
        **GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates** 
    ]
});
```

Should be used as well.

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    if (!newPresence.member.user.bot && newPresence.streaming) {
        console.log(`${newPresence.member.user.tag} started streaming!`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sidenote: You might also want to check if `!oldPresence.streaming` in your condition. `voiceStateUpdate` fires for a lot of reasons including muting and unmuting in which case the current code would still print that someone started streaming when they are already streaming but just muted themselves.